# Deserializing XML from the web

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Generally, this is how I deserialize an XML file:

```
    string location = "C:\\test.xml";
    XmlObjectClass member_data = new XmlObjectClass();

                using (Stream XmlStream = new FileStream(location,FileMode.Open))
                {
                    data = (XmlObjectClass)serializer.Deserialize(XmlStream);
                }
```

This works when I'm desrializing an XML file, but what if I want to deserialize an XML that is returned by a web request (i.e. going to a URL)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there are a few options:

- Create an `XmlReader` with [`XmlReader.Create(uri)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx) and deserialize directly
- Get the stream from the `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`, and deserialize from the stream
- Fetch all the data, then build a stream around it using `MemoryStream` and deserialize from that

If you don't need to do anything special with the web request - i.e. it's really just a "GET" from a URI - then the first option is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the response is saved in memory, you can use a `MemoryStream`, a `StringReader`, or such a class that fits the format of the data and the capabilities of [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize.aspx).